# Session variables not the same across php pages

Tags: php, session

Duly note, I am using `session_start();` preceding any code in both these php files:

Problem in a minimally-reduced format:

index.php

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['msg'] = 'hello';
?>
```

When invoking add_to_cart.php using ajax in index.php:

```
              $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"add_to_cart.php",
                async: false, //tested with this true and now false
                data:{test_product:productName},
                success:function(response){
                  alert(response);
                }
              });
```

add_to_cart.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    echo json_encode($_SESSION['msg']);
?>
```

The output of the alert is `null`

I am running php 7.4 on nginx, on ubuntu.

Comment: If the `add_to_cart.php` is called by ajax it is probably opening a new session with the server what causes your issue. As a good practice I recommend saving the user's session in the database (there are plenty of guides how to do that).

Comment: Is there a reason for using array push as opposed to something like $_SESSION['cart'][] = array(new stuff)?

Comment: I have tried that, but it isn't adding the previous session cart items. It only contains the latest item sent through ajax.

Comment: @kerbholz yes, sorry. A bit misleading. In my actual IDE, it isn't commented, but I commented it on S/O to highlight it. Bad choice, I'll uncomment it. But the issue still persists.

Comment: Well, ok. Is the output just `null` or `[[null,null]]`? Have you made sure that the `$_POST` vars are actually set? Are you calling/including `index.php` somewhere or have another call to `$_SESSION['cart'] = array();` somewhere in an included file? That code as it is should work just fine

Comment: Yes the $_POST values are set, I have run a few console.log() in JS to check their values are set.

The echo prints only "null" for the code solution shown above.

Comment: Assuming both `$_POST` vars are empty, it should print `[[null,null]]` though. Use `var_dump($_SESSION['cart']` before your `json_encode()`. And maybe post the AJAX code you use. If it outputs `null` it means `$_SESSION['cart']` is not set

Comment: @kerbholz both POST vars are not empty, although I am seeing NULL for the vardump. Please see the original post, I have uploaded the ajax code as well as the var dump. Thanks

Comment: "_both POST vars are not empty_" Check again, please, `$_POST["product_quantity"]` is not sent in your Ajax request - at least this one should be empty. Are you calling your ajax code from `index.php` or calling `index.php` before, thus initializing `$_SESSION['cart']`? I can reproduce your output (NULL) if I `unset($_SESSION['cart']);`, I can't reproduce if I use the same code as you did. Good luck

Comment: @kerbholz Thanks for your help so far, I have completely rewritten the entire issue in a minimum-reduced format. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

Remove `$_SESSION['cart'] = array();` from index.php

And save item in cart as following in add_to_cart.php.

```
$_SESSION['cart'][] = [$productName,$productQty];
```

Comment: It cannot be used by the other php file. It's only set in the php file used for ajax. And also, it needs to append it and not set it. (array_push). Thanks though.

Comment: Good solution though - still it isn't keepign the previous values added in. It just only maintains the one recently added through ajax.

Comment: @Neil please can you confirm if you have `session_start();` in the page from where you are calling the ajax request ?

Comment: I can confirm it is there, at the very top of the page <?php session_start(); ?> this bit here.

Comment: Can you find out on all the places where you unset session or reassign value to session. 
because now things seem to look fine, as you are able to save one product, but I'm assuming in your code somewhere you unset the session or reassign empty array to it.

Comment: Can you please try one more thing, add `async: false` in your Ajax request and try

Comment: Added that, but not changed anything.

Comment: I have rewritten the entire original post in a minimal-reduced format.

Comment: I just created your example on my local host it's working fine, i also tried added elements into session cart array that is also working fine, please see this [screenshot](https://snipboard.io/6bKwN3.jpg).

Comment: Yup. I have tested on another machine running Apache instead of Nginx. It worked fine. It is probably an issue with the server. Thank you for your help. I will give you best answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested on another machine running Apache instead of Nginx and it worked. The var_dump of session immediately on the ajax php file was null on nginx however, had contents intact on the apache server.